# py2applet and PIL do not work together

Tags: python-imaging-library, py2app

I have this very simple python script that works perfectly when I launch the script from the terminal.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.png')
im.show()
```

But then I tried to use py2applet to create a Mac app from it. It works but the all crashes. Googling around I found out that PIL/Pillow and py2app do no go along very well but I couldn't find a clear solution. 
I get this error log

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem although I'm not very sure how. I list here the changes I made in case it's useful for someone to actually understand.

1) "import Image" does not work. I needed "from PIL import image"

2) "py2applet script.py" does not work I needed to create the setup.py first with the option --make-setup and then make the applet with "python setup.py py2app" (N.B.: No -A option)

3) Probably the most important I had to manually move Pillow-3.1.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/. It was previously into /Libraries I think.